# how to make ticks function work in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have created x-axis and define the ticks value as 5 and its working fine. But if i want exactly 7 ticks in the axis. I cant get it to work.

I made some search and found an answer that `ticks can take only multiple of 2,5,10 not any number`. But i am in an scenario that i want to get exactly 7 ticks and i am unable to get it.

Is there any way to get it work? [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/RX7z7WGBBs8EMNZKLIFI?p=preview)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your purpose if you give the tick values itself

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                   .scale(axisScale)
                   .tickValues([10, 20, 30, 50, 60, 80, 100]);//tick values as per your choice
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GRKpG043FmBLS6Lu3QgS?p=preview)

Comment: Actually that trick works for me. But is that true? "ticks can take only multiple of 2,5,10 not any number"

Comment: Didn't find anything in the docs ... but it appears your finding are true :)

Comment: How can i get the width between the ticks if we use tickValues?

Comment: Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/Gl4k3vgbqzHIpCTlzcwr?p=preview you can get the position of the tick from where you can calculate the width.

Comment: Thats the perfect thing that i want. U just saved my day